# Got "Operation Failed" Error Randomly when try to send ANY emails from Microsoft Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, terminal, microsoft-office, office365, windows-server-2012-r2

We have **Microsoft Office 2016** installed on Windows **Server 2012R2** (Terminal Servers) Based on **Office 365** on-Premise.

Random users reporting often that they just cant send emails, and they got that annoying error randomly:

[image]

Now, until last friday everything was smooth.
On friday microsoft activated a new Authentication method for using Office 2016.
It seems that MS admit the issue since they said:

> Root cause: A recent authentication change has introduced a problem
>   where users with multiple accounts are unable to authenticate to the
>   service properly, preventing them from accessing their mailboxes.

Ofcourse, they dont really have a solution for that manner.

How do i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

See this thread : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-operation-failed/4b7cbac8-133d-4571-a3d8-29167c919e18?page=4

Seems be related to this :

### #

EX186990 - Can't forward emails using Outlook desktop client

Update : 2019-08-07 02:58 (UTC)
Start : 2019-08-01 03:03 (UTC)

Degradation of the service
Impact sur les utilisateurs:Users may be unable to forward some emails using the Outlook desktop client.

Dernier message:Title: Can't forward emails using Outlook desktop client

User Impact: Users may be unable to forward some emails using the Outlook desktop client.
More info: This issue only affects email forwarding. Users experiencing the problem will receive an "operation failed" error when attempting to forward emails. Mail send/receive is unaffected.

While we're focused on resolving the issue, users may be able to leverage Outlook on the web to forward emails.

Current status: We've been unable to identify the cause of this issue with the previously gathered information. If your users are experiencing this problem, we request that your representatives reach out to us to help gather additional data for our investigation.

Scope of impact: For affected customers, impact is specific to users attempting to forward mail through the Outlook desktop client.

Next update by: Wednesday, August 7, 2019, at 7:30 PM UTC

### #

workaround : 
1) Rich Text format rather than HTML mail
or
2) pass in Exchange Cache mode (no online mode)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed alread. Refer to this information:

In the ticket EX186990 - Can't forward emails using Outlook desktop client stated that this issue is resolved and what the root cause is:

tart time: Wednesday, July 31, 2019, at 9:41 AM UTC

End time: Wednesday, August 7, 2019, at 10:30 PM UTC

Root cause: A recent code change that was intended to improve performance and minimize crashes inadvertently resulted in the inability to forward or reply to some emails.

Next steps:
- We're working to identify the content in the previous update that led to this problem.
- Once identified, we'll address the code issue to ensure that no further impact arises when this update is re-introduced to the environment.

This is the final update for the event.

Related link: [O365 user keeps getting error when forwarding mails or replying](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ac5c5240-2e61-4394-9c30-6b0bc0937aef/o365-user-keeps-getting-error-when-forwarding-mails-or-replying?forum=outlook)